# RQ - ImportError: No module named XXX

Tags: python, flask, redis, backgroundworker, apscheduler

I am having issues with an rq worker.

This is the structure of my app:

```
app/
    run.py
    project/
        __init__.py
        clock.py
        views.py
        worker.py
        controllers/
           __init__.py
           leads_fb.py
```

clock is executed once I run my app and this is the code:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from rq import Queue, get_current_job
from rq.job import Job 
from worker import conn
from controllers import leads_fb
import logging
import os


q = Queue(connection=conn)
sched = BackgroundScheduler()

def enque_jobs():
    info = '1aooEOTBQz1pAW915-JonL3Jh2mhclR5EZTHGotFBe7s||blah blah blah'
    job = q.enqueue(leads_fb.prueba, info)  
    print 'This job is run every 3 seconds.'

if os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") == "true":
    sched.add_job(enque_jobs, 'interval', seconds=3)
    sched.start()

log = logging.getLogger('apscheduler.executors.default')
# log.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # DEBUG

# fmt = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
h = logging.StreamHandler()
# h.setFormatter(fmt)
log.addHandler(h)
then clock enqueues jobs with the rq worker which is worker.py:

import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

and the function that the queued job is execution is controllers/leads_fb.py:

```
from wksh import init_wksh, get_last_row, write_in_cell

def prueba(info):
    print 'aaaaa'
    info = info.split('||')
    id_client = info[0]
    str_prueba = info[1]
    wksh = init_wksh(id_client)
    print wksh
    row = get_last_row(wksh)

    write_in_cell(wksh,'A'+str(row),str_prueba)
    print 'funciona  ' + str(row)
```

when I run my app with the run.py file in the root directory it gives me the error: ImportError: No module named project.controllers.leads_fb

my run.py file has this code:

```
from project import app
from project import worker
from project import clock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='127.0.0.1', port=1234)
```

and my app/project/init.py file has this

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

from . import views
from . import worker
from . import clock
```

Please help!! I've been stuck with this for a week and can't manage to fix this. I have read other thread issues and have come to understand it has to do something with the PYTHONPATH that points my module directory to my rq worker but I have no idea how to implement this.

**how can I add the import path to my worker.py file? I have tested and if I start the worker in the root directory with the command line 'rqworker' it works fine. My app thinks that the worker.py file is in the root directory, but it's actually in project/ inside the root directory. How and where do I specify this so it works locally and also deployed in Heroku?**

Answer (score 0):

Is this your error msg? "ImportError: No module named config"

You miss a config.py for the line

```
app.config.from_object('config')
```

[from_object(obj)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Config.from_object): 
the obj could be

1. the object with that name will be imported
2. an actual object reference: that object is used directly

So, in order to make 'config' valid, you could create a config.py under /app

Comment: my error message is ImportError: No module named project.controllers.leads_fb ! I do have the config.py file in the root directory.